# Can't take input in a dynamically allocated string in c

Tags: c, string, memory, input

I've been writing a HTML generator in C. After some research I found some code that allows me to take input in a array that allocates more memory to it if you need it. The problem is that after a couple of times, the code stops working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *inputString(FILE *fp, size_t size);

int main(){
    char *nameOfFile;
    char *multiF;
    int choice;
    FILE *f;
    printf("Name of file: ");
    nameOfFile=inputString(stdin, 10);
    f = fopen(strcat(nameOfFile,".html"),"w+");
    fprintf(f, "<head>\n");
    printf("Title: ");
    multiF=inputString(stdin, 10);
    fprintf(f, "\t<title>%s</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n", multiF);
    while(choice != 99){ //Code stops working in while loop
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("[1]Headings\n");
        printf("[2]Paragraphs\n");
        printf("[99]Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("What size[1-6]? ");
                scanf("%d",&choice);
                if(choice < 7 && choice > 0){
                    printf("Heading[%d]:",choice);
                    multiF=inputString(stdin,10);
                    fprintf(f,"<h%d>%s</h%d>",choice,multiF,choice);
                }else{
                    printf("Input something useful...\n");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Paragraph: ");
                multiF=inputString(stdin,10);
                fprintf(f,"<p>%s</p>",multiF);
                break;
            case 99:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Input something useful...\n");
        }
    }
    fprintf(f,"</body>");
    free(multiF);
    free(nameOfFile);
    return 0;
}

char *inputString(FILE *fp, size_t size){
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len=0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}
```

Comment: `strcat(nameOfFile,".html")` writes into invalid memory locations as `nameOfFile` hasn't got any more space. Fix by `nameOfFile = realloc(nameOfFile, strlen(nameOfFile) + 5);` before calling `fopen`.

Comment: You have memory leaks, you do `multiF=inputString(stdin, 10);` multiple times without freeing the memory in between.

Comment: Note: You forgot to `fclose(f);`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the code stops working"? *How* does it stop working? Does the program just exit? Do you get a crash? Unexpected output? If you get crashes or unexpected exits, try running in a debugger to catch the crash in action.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg <- When it's supposed to take input in the switches, it doesn't. Just skips to next instruction. Freeing the memory in the start of the while loop doesn't work too.
Cool Guy <- I did both of your suggestions. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Well first of all you have *undefined behavior* as you use the uninitialized variable `choice` in a comparison. Then you should *still* use a debugger, to step through the code line by line. Both to see that the input function works as it's intended, then to see what input you actually get (and remember to check what `scanf ` returns).

Comment: Change `scanf("%d", &choice);` to `scanf("%d%*c", &choice);`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But won't `realloc()` free the old memory automatically?

Comment: @sunqingyao Except that the OP never passes in the old pointer to the `inputString` function, so can't use it for reallocation. Also in `inputString` the OP is doing `realloc` on a `NULL` pointer, which is the same a `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inputString(char **str, FILE *fp); // No char *str, because we need to change the value of pointer str

int main(){
    char *nameOfFile = malloc(0);
    char *multiF = malloc(0); // Calling malloc() for later free()
    int choice = 0; // Initialization
    FILE *f;
    printf("Name of file: ");
    inputString(&nameOfFile, stdin);
    nameOfFile = realloc(nameOfFile, strlen(nameOfFile) + 5); // You need more memory for ".html"
    strcat(nameOfFile, ".html");
    f = fopen(nameOfFile, "w");
    fprintf(f, "<head>\n");
    printf("Title: ");
    inputString(&multiF, stdin);
    fprintf(f, "\t<title>%s</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n", multiF);
    while(choice != 99){
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("[1]Headings\n");
        printf("[2]Paragraphs\n");
        printf("[99]Exit\n");
        scanf(" %d%*c", &choice); // " %d" to discard whitespace characters, and "%*c" to consume '\n'
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("What size[1-6]? ");
                scanf(" %d%*c", &choice);
                if(choice < 7 && choice > 0){
                    printf("Heading[%d]:", choice);
                    inputString(&multiF, stdin);
                    fprintf(f, "<h%d>%s</h%d>", choice, multiF, choice);
                }else{
                    printf("Input something useful...\n");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Paragraph: ");
                inputString(&multiF, stdin);
                fprintf(f, "<p>%s</p>", multiF);
                break;
            case 99:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Input something useful...\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    fprintf(f, "</body>");
    free(multiF);
    free(nameOfFile);
    fclose(f); // Don't forget to close the file
    return 0;
}

void inputString(char **str, FILE *fp){
    int ch;
    size_t size = 1, index = 0;
    free(*str);
    *str = malloc(size);
    if(!*str)
        return;
    while(EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        (*str)[index++] = ch;
        if(index == size){
            *str = realloc(*str, size += 16); // sizeof (char) is guaranteed to be 1 by the standard
            if(!*str)
                return;
        }
    }
    (*str)[index] = '\0'; // No need to increase index
}
```

See my comments for the details.

There are some issues in your code:

1. After `scanf("%d",&choice);`, a '\n' will be left in `stdin`. When it is met by `inputStrng()`, the function stops generating string immediately.
2. To change the value of a pointer variable in a function, you need to pass a pointer to pointer, such as `char **str`.
3. You forgot to close the file, which may cause information loss.